# Unity Canvas "Scale With Screen Size" makes Elements unseeable in lower Resolutions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `Info Text` in my Game that just says `"Open (E)"` whenever the `Player` is looking at something like a `door` or a `chest`. The info text is surrounded by a rectangle.

If i just leave the Canvas at `Constant Pixel Size` the `info text` + `rectangle` is way to big if you play at 1280x720. (I'm developing in 1920x1080 by the way).

However if i set the Canvas to `Scale With Screen Size`, the rectangle isn't seeable anymore, and the text looks blurry.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `Scale With Screen Size` option before adding any thing to canvas. Readjust the `text` object by setting the `Game` tab resolution to the one you have given as reference in `Canvas Scaler`.

This tutorial might help you more :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=95q79j0lNYA